# CSS url path on fill property not working

Tags: css, url, firefox, webkit, fill

I'm having a problem with a fill property on an `<svg>`. I'm using url() which refers to an id, however, depending on the type of path I specify, it either works in Webkit browsers or in Firefox, but never in both:

```
.fill {
  fill: url(index.php?#pattern);     /* works in webkit, not in firefox */
  fill: url(#pattern);               /* works in webkit, not in firefox */
  fill: url(../index.php?#pattern);  /* works in firefox, not in webkit */
}
```

Comment: _Update:_

It's been a while since I asked this question. I checked again to make sure the question is still relevant, messed around with the code, but nothing seems to change this.